# Debian 3D Acceleration with Intel HD 3000

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, xfce, kodi

I'm looking at installing XBMC in Debian on a mATX PC I'll use as both a NAS and HTPC.

I am currently researching the actual components that will make up this computer and I'm considering how graphics need to be accounted for. I don't know exactly what Xorg is, technically, all I know is it's needed for graphics environments.

Anyway, I want to use XFCE on Debian but for 1080p decoding with built in Intel HD 300 graphics I assume some special drivers are needed to take advantage of this? No doubt this would 'just work' out the box on Windows, but I want to use Linux for its features that make running a NAS on it more power-user friendly.

*tldr*:
**What exactly are the technical considerations that need to be made with getting integrated graphics hardware acceleration working under Linux (Debian) environments? Must I make it work with Xorg, XFCE *and* the media player itself (XMBC)?**

Comment: X.org supplies hardware acceleration. XFCE and XMBC run on top of it and use the hardware acceleration it provides.

Comment: So how do I set up Xorg to enable hardware acceleration? Do I install the drivers via Xorg or does it somehow (how?) pickup that the correct drivers are installed somewhere? I have no experience of setting up drivers under Linux, in the past I've never needed to (or generic ones have done).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69695/driver-for-intel-hd-3000-core-i7-2630qm) say that the Intel HD 3000 card should work out of the box on Ubuntu 11.10, no tweaking needed. This appears to be a relatively recent occurrence.

I *think* this means it should also work out of the box on Debian, as long as the kernel is >= 2.6.39. As of last September [this required a backport](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/15050/intel-hd-graphics-3000-sandy-bridge-vs-2-kernels/) for Squeeze. So Wheezy, which comes with more recent kernels, may be an easier option.

Comment: I need it to work on Debian. All the bloat that comes with Ubuntu is unnecessary to me.

Comment: Doh! Had AskUbuntu open and got mixed up. I _think_ it should also work out of the box on Debian, as long as the kernel is >= 2.6.39. As of last September, this [required a backport](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/15050/intel-hd-graphics-3000-sandy-bridge-vs-2-kernels/) for Squeeze, so Wheezy may be an easier option.

Comment: That's really helpful James, thanks for finding that for me. Perhaps you should edit your answer to contain the above and then your downvote will magically become an upvote/accepted answer. :$ :)

Answer (score 0):

This works out of the box for me with Xubuntu 64 bit. Video playback is fine. I think missing pixel shader support (or maybe HD3000 doesn't have that anyway).